# Computer freezes for seconds at a time

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Sometimes, my PC (win7, 64 bit version.) will freeze for 5-10 seconds.

- Sometimes the mouse cursor still moves, but my actions do not do anything. Sometimes the mouse cursor is frozen too.
- It usually happens a few minutes after boot, but well after all the start-up tasks have "died down".
- One of the most sure-fire ways to induce it is to browse to a stackexchange site that uses the LaTeX plugin. [Math Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) will do this almost every time, but only the first time I visit it.

Based on cursory research my first suspect is the HDD so I:

1. Updated the drivers of the motherboard and the bios to the latest version.
2. Read out the SMART data of my disk. It shows the disk to be healthy with 0 recorded retries.

The problem still persists, and it is quite annoying.

Can anyone offer any specific insights, or point me toward a general troubleshooting strategy?

Comment: Additional hardware/configuration info is of course available upon request. I did not with to spam the question with my shopping list, as I presume most of it is irrelevant.

Comment: adding to what Red said, the w7 Resource Monitor is some kick butt tool, wow i never thought about it even, it is ONE thing in 7 that is cool and functional and usable :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Sysinternal ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) should help you identify what is causing the freeze.

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any tips regarding what I should be looking for?